# Load java function in Lua

Tags: java, lua

Simple **QUESTION** : Are there ways to run or load java functions inside Lua?

I am trying to create a phone application that transfers files between server and client using Lua. The server uses Java while client uses Lua.

this is a lua function that receives file

```
function UDPClientModule.receiveFile()
    local data, status
    local chunks = {}
    while true do
        data, status = udp:receive()
        print("status: ", status)
        if data ~= nil then
            table.insert(chunks, data)
            --the filename is the last chunk to be received
            if string.match(data, ".jpg") then
                -- but strangely returns true 
                break
            end
        end
        socket.sleep(0.5)
    end
    --combineAndOpenImage(t)
end
```

No problems so far. However, the chunks sent by the server are encapsulated in a class like this:

```
public class FileChunk {
    private List<Data> dataList; 
    //functions below
}
public class Data{
    private byte[] fileData;
    // functions and adding file headers below
} // then UDPServer.java sends bytes of FileChunk
```

Because of this, packets received by the lua function are strange which also results in `string.match(data, ".jpg")` returning true. So I want to run java files (eg. UDPClient.java) in order to receive and decipher the chunks, instead of lua.

I don't want to change the server nor migrate the client language to java. I haven't found any resources about this so I need help.

Comment: Don't rely on `the filename is the last chunk to be received`.  Use other methods to detect the last chunk.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Noted. But the issue is that I cannot decode the chunks using Lua. I may want to run a java helper file instead.

Comment: @warspyking LuaJ is used to run Lua scripts inside Java files. But how about running Java functions inside Lua files?

Comment: To decode the chunks using Lua, you have to know incoming data format.  It is enough to write decoder in any programming language.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I know the format of the chunks. But I do not know to decode chunks created by java to Lua and I don't have the resources to follow.

Comment: Create test file and send it from server to client.  For example, file's content may be a sequence of 8-byte strings 'Obito001', 'Obito002', and so on.  Then just analyze what client has received on Lua side.  I think you can easily "decode" the format used by Java.  I hope the payload will not be zipped on transmission.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a wrapper library, such as the ones in C. I do not know how, but I hope this provides you a sense of direction.